# How to set up a node http proxy to intercept a particular request/response?

Tags: node.js, https, puppeteer, http-proxy

I am making a nodejs pupeteer app that loads a web page. In that page, many resources are loaded. The pupeteer API for intercepting requets/response seems to not work for all resources, so I want to use an http proxy.

I want to intercept a particular request/response in my proxy. If the remote server sends back a response with the first line of the content being the word "cat", then I want to console.log that resource URL before I forward the response back to the client. The request may use https. How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: I've done this before with any-proxy, for https you have to generate a cert and --disable-web-security or add the cert to your trusted certs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://anyproxy.io/en/#use-anyproxy-as-an-npm-module

First install AnyProxy

For Debian / Ubuntu Users, first do:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Then install AnyProxy:

```
npm install -g anyproxy
```

You need to write a rule to intercept responses which start with cat, and console.log. So maybe something like this:

```
// file: sample.js
module.exports = {
  summary: 'a rule to log responses starting with cat',
  *beforeSendResponse(requestDetail, responseDetail) {
    if responseDetail.body.startsWith("cat "){
         console.log(responseDetail.body);
    }
  },
};
```

AnyProxy does not intercept https request by default. To view decryptd info, you have to config the CA certificate.

```
anyproxy-ca #generate root CA. manually trust it after that.
anyproxy --intercept --rule sample.js #launch anyproxy and intercept all https traffic, and use sample.js rule
```

You may have to do other configuration stuff depending on your setup, but once you set it up writing rules for intercepting responses seems straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

https://anyproxy.io/en/#use-anyproxy-as-an-npm-module

First install node if not installed and then install AnyProxy
npm install -g anyproxy

Write a rule to intercept responses that start with cat. It maybe something like this:

```
// file: sample.js
module.exports = {
  summary: 'a rule to log responses starting with cat',
  *beforeSendResponse(requestDetail, responseDetail) {
    if responseDetail.body.startsWith("cat "){
         console.log(responseDetail.body);
    }
  },
};
```

Same way AnyProxy also supports the beforeSendRequest method too for intercepting requests.